# Why is spider angioma more frequently seen in the distribution of superior vena cava?

Tags: liver

From textbooks and my personal experience, spider angioma is more frequently seen in upper body. But is there any research for the root cause of this phenomenon? I've searched but haven't seen anything helpful.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a question that would gather much research interest.

Comment: Since the etiology of spider angiomas is unknown, the reason for their peculiar distribution also remains a mystery.